# sqlite multiple databases insert/update/delete

Tags: sqlite, concurrency

I was wondering how SQLite behaves when it's given multiple databases to insert/update/delete in at the same time? Does it spawn multiple processes which can in theory have better concurrency than using a single database/single process or it utilizes the same process for each?

Searching through the documentation didn't provide e with a definitive answer. I am aware that SQLite isn't the most ideal environment for multiple writes, as the database resides in as single file. But does that mean that multiple files = different write processes?

```
databaseOne = connectToSqlite('databaseOne'); 
databaseTwo = connectToSqlite('databaseTwo');
function write()
    queryDatabaseOne("INSERT SOMETHING INTO SOME_TABLE VALUES SOME_VALUES");
    queryDatabaseTwo("INSERT SOMETHING INTO SOME_TABLE VALUES SOME_VALUES");
```

So, two different sqlite databases, and two inserts executed in parallel, towards tables in the two databases.

Thanks

Comment: What does this mean: 'multiple databases to insert/update/delete in at the same time'?  Perhaps you should provide a code sample?

Comment: The question wasn't about a particular implementation - it's more of a theoretical one. But I see how it may be confusing. I'll add some pseudo-code to the question to clarify a bit.

Comment: I do not recognize 'queryDatabaseOne()'.  Is it non-blocking?  If it is blocking, then the inserts are not executed in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, database queries are blocking - they do not return until they are complete.  This helps secure the integrity of the database.  The SQLITE API is blocking.

Of course, if you have a multiple databases, then you can write a multi-threaded application with non-blocking routines that call the the SQLITE API and then code overlapping, parallel inserts to the multiple databases.  You will have to be careful about all the usual things in a multithreaded application - the SQLITE API will neither help not hinder - with added complication of insuring that there in no possibility of overlapping accesses to the SAME database.